# Replace empty Strings of csv file columns to NULL while loading into table

Tags: bash, csv, db2

I'm loading a DB2 table from a file in a script using the format LOAD FROM ${CSVFILE} OF DEL REPLACE INTO T_TABLE. When the column value is "" , SQL Developer will display value as (null) but this is not an actual null. The behavior I want is to get this value set as NULL so the column default value gets set. How can I make it so in case of empty string it will set NULL value in DB?

Comment: What's the db2 platform and version?

Comment: V11.5.6.0 special_13320

Comment: What's the platform (OS)?

Comment: Unix using a csh script

Answer (score 1):

You may use [EXTERNAL TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-external-table) functionality for that, because it's not so easy to make `LOAD` convert empty values into NULLs with [user exit](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=data-moving-using-customized-application-user-exit) application.

```
db2 "declare c1 cursor for select nullif (a, '') as a, b from external '${CSVFILE}' (a varchar (10), b int) using (delimiter ',' quotedvalue double)"
db2 "load from c1 of cursor replace into T_TABLE"
```

Notes:
You have to describe all the file fields appropriately in the `DECLARE CURSOR` command.
You may use another appropriate options (ENCODING, CRINSTRING, LFINSTRING, etc.) in the `USING` clause - refer to the 1-st link for more details.